# Numbers and Letters in Boxes

Tags: word

For the last training session of collaboration training, the group were taken to the brainstorm room.

There were 8 boxes with something written text at the base.

[image]

The instruction was :

**Can you collaborate and determine what is in the boxes?**

Rules :

1) You may Mix, Match, shuffle, reshuffle the contents and pass it around.

2) Think inside the box, about the box and around the box

Your time starts now

---

In case somebody needs it in text format.

```
4A2P            5N          2M1Y    


1C7R                        1J1V    


6E4S            1H4T        1I7U
```

Hint 1

> Put same number of Letter BLOCKS (Cubes) in each box corresponding to the number and shuffle it around.

Comment: Looks like the contents are all in the form of a number followed by a letter. I assume we're not supposed to rip those apart and send a letter to one box and a number to another?

Comment: @Kingrames You have assumed correct.

Comment: I see every vowel except for O. Is this a case of "you have 4 a's, 2 p's, 5 n's, etc and you have to assemble them into words?"

Comment: Looks like a bunch of proteins to me

Comment: @Kingrames That is right, no O's

Comment: So we just rearrange the letters AAAAPPNNNNNMMYCRRRRRRRJVEEEEEESSSSHTTTTIUUUUUUU until we make some words? sounds easy enough.

Comment: @Kingrames you Sir are a good puzzler.

Comment: Lemme go get my alphabet blocks and we can get started!

Comment: @Kingrames You Rock !!!

Comment: Is collaboration a key component, or is this solvable by a single person?

Comment: @IanMacDonald Can be solved by a single person. Collaboration in the sense that two or more brains "might" arrive at a solution quicker. Also Collaboration is a hint. ;-)

Comment: Nurse, can a near-state hunt nurture my super jumper virus?

Comment: @GordonK Lol , good anagram.

Comment: Pretty sure the box in the bottom middle contains one hat.

Comment: Runt cat's unseen urine aura just hurt my upper arm nerves!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is:

> Mercury 
>  Venus
>  Earth
>  Mars
>  Jupiter
>  Saturn
>  Uranus
>  Neptune
>  This is obtained by taking the number of each letter (e.g. 4 As, 2 Ps, etc.) and rearranging them.
>  Thanks to Kingrames for the pointer